# Android - AsyncTask Socket Write Timeout

Tags: android, sockets, timeout, android-asynctask

I have a background alarm running every minute using the example posted here:

[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

My actual alarm launches an AsyncTask (since I am doing a network transaction), that looks like this:

```
Socket sock = new Socket("hostname.com", 1234);
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        String data = "beth";
        out.write(data.getBytes());
        sock.close();
```

What's the easiest way to make this timeout in case the network connection is unstable? I am already checking to see if the phone is connected to wifi.

setSoTimeout looks similar to what I want to use, but it appears to be only for sockets that are receiving content. I want the connection to give up after a few seconds if it fails to connect.

**In response to the first comment:**

Before I was running:

```
new Checkin().execute();
```

Do I now run:

```
new Checkin().get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

To timeout after 10 seconds? And this will stop the asynctask after 10 seconds?

Comment: This question could be help you out:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882739/android-setting-a-timeout-for-an-asynctask

Comment: Thanks! Please see my added code above - is this the proper way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: I tried the code I posted above, and not it isn't executing the asynctask at all - am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I am currently receiving a: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException on the second line shown above, but it shouldn't be timing out - it should take under 10 seconds easily. It's transmitting a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use connect() method

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, port), 10000);
```

Comment: N.B. This will allow you to set a *connection* timeout, but it will not provide a timeout for `out.write()`. I don't know which the OP was looking for, but sometimes you need the latter (or both).