# Display progress dialog till a condition will be true or time ended

Tags: java, android

I have an app that user submit the log in form , **when it sent the data** to server and **create a connection** for its account.

In this connection i have an integer field named as **state**.
**the state value** is : **1 for connecting**, **2 for connected** and  **0 for failed**.

I want to **show a dialog** to user show is `Connecting ...` and then check the state of connection **if its return 0 or 2 dismiss the dialog** and show the related message **else if it doesn't change after 15 sec dismiss dialog** and change the state to 0 !

How can i do this logic ?

Comment: what you have tried so far ? or straight asking for code ?

Comment: Im not sure where and how i can start !

Comment: I guess you want to implement a timeout logic. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882739/android-setting-a-timeout-for-an-asynctask)  question can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming to make the network all you are using an Asynctask. In this case you can use the methods onPreExecute and onPostExecute.

For more information about network calls and Asynctasks, please read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html. I've given a brief explanation below though.

If you create a dialog or initialise it in your onCreate method (or something similar), you can call the below methods to show and hide the dialog when the call starts and finishes

```
onPreExecute() {
    dialog.show();
}

onPostExecute(Object result) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

You can also modify the UI from doInBackground through the use of onProgressUpdate(). This will allow you to call to the dialog whilst performing the logic in doInBackground by calling the method publishProgress(). The exact place you should call the method I'm not sure of because I don't fully understand your bigger picture but I hope this helps you along the way

Comment: thanks for answer! but im using async task for my connection and i  change the state in `onPostExecute`, my problem is i want to check state when its change before 15 second show a dialog to user that he is loged in or any error else or show a fail message after 15 sec

Comment: I've amended my answer with a method that will allow you to change the dialog half way through a doInBackground call

Comment: as you say **half way** , my problem is in the other half :D

Comment: can you tell me how can i finish doInBackground  method in a limit time ?

Comment: I have an idea of using a Handler with a 15 second timer, and using a flag that is checked in doInBackground. If this flag was set to true, the doInBackground would return null. I'm not on my machine right now so cannot test it hence why I can give just ideas and brief implementations

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.You could also use [AsyncTask.onCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28%29)

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{
    private Dialog dialog;
@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    //relevant activity code.
    TestAsync ta=new TestAsync().execute();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ta.cancel();
            if(dialog!=null)
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }15*1000);

}


public class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {




@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    //create your dialog here

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    if(dialog!=null){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //relevant AsyncTask code
}


}

}
```