# Execute Asynctask for specific time period

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to execute Asynctask only for 3 minutes. After 3 minutes it should be terminate. Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Setting a Timeout for an AsyncTask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882739/android-setting-a-timeout-for-an-asynctask)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout for an asynctask. Somethink like :

```
asyncTask.get(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882739/android-setting-a-timeout-for-an-asynctask)

Comment: thanks for responding. but actually i am executing asynctask inside  onPostExecute() of same asynctask again and again. and i want this process works for 3 minutes only