# get right cellID in android network?

Tags: android, cellid

i have been working to find right CellID in android network. i am trying to search tutorial, i found the solution something like this:

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
```

Then to access CellID, use this code:

```
cellLocation.getCid() % 0xffff
```

When i run the apps, i got an ID number. But, the problem is different IDCELL with G Nettrack apps as reference. Then, the CELLID doesn't match with original data.
Please help! Thanks

Comment: Which network type? LTE?

Comment: i have been trying on 3g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing wrong calculation.
For GSM network: it should be '&' instead of '%'

```
GsmCellLocation loc = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
 if (loc != null) 
  {
  long cellID = loc.getCid() & 0xffff;
  }
```

For 4g/LTE cellid's, there is a good article written [here](http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2058551).follow that.

Comment: I think question have been deleted.

Comment: this. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245777/how-to-set-time-out-for-asynctask-execution/