# java - make if for async task time limit

Tags: java, android

here is my piece of code:

```
Thread  one = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            new LongOperation(finalJson)
                .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
                .get(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
one.start();
```

i want to say if `AsyncTask` past 30000 MILLISECONDS and didn't finish the job return a message, how i can code this? thanks

Comment: ok sir thanks for your tip

Comment: and you are doing fine what is the problem ?

Comment: Your code example uses a `Thread`, not an `AsyncTask` as you ask about in your question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice He is using asyncTask inside a thread which may be incorrect 
it should be thread inside asyncTask

Comment: i am talking with a server but i made a time limitation i want to say if we past that time make all things null and just return a message

Comment: @Basil Battikhi  why it would be incorrect  ? i just did it to stop freezing the ui

Comment: The main thread in android is UI Thread you can't execute another thread like network thread directly, the application will stop responding due to you are doing a long operation in ui thread which will probably stop your application

Comment: @MrTaha An `AsyncTask` already spawns another thread to do its work. Creating a thread with `new Thread()` just creates unnecessary overhead from what I can tell.

Comment: i got what you said this things happens when internet speed is  low so i got why it happens

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if i use asynctask with time limitation directly it will freez ui

Comment: It's not related to internet speed, and if your internet speed is so fast your customers will not have this speed, but there are some rules.

Comment: @Gourango Sutradhar solution would be good for you

Comment: ok i will try this sir thanks for your feed back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Setting a Timeout for an AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882739/android-setting-a-timeout-for-an-asynctask)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing it using an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Copy-pasting from the link:

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
> allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the
> UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
> and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
> should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
> most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
> it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
> java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
> FutureTask.

Said this, configuring an AsyncTask is pretty simple, just create a class like the following:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //this method works on the UI thread.
        //this is the first to run before "doInBackground"
        mTextView.setText("we start!");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       try {
          //do whatever your async task needs to do. This method works async
          //you can also call an UI callback from here with the publishProgress method. This will call the "onProgressUpdate" method, and it has to respect his type.
          publishProgress("we go on!");
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         Thread.interrupted();
       }
       return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      //this method works on the UI thread
      //it get the "doInBackground" return value.
      mTextView.setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
       //this method works on UI thread, so it can access UI components and ctx
       mTextView.setText(values[0]);
    }
}
```

This is a basic example on how to create an AsyncTask, you can use it like this (form activity/fragment):

```
AsyncTaskExample asyncTask = new AsyncTaskExample();
asyncTask.get(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This will set a timeout on your async operation. [Look here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) for the exact Exception/return

For any further question, ask freely. Hope this helps

## Edit:

I just noticed you have an `AsyncTask` inside your thread. Since `AsyncTask` *is already async*, I would avoid doing this and simply call the `AsyncTask` with the method I gave you before. In that way the `AsyncTask` will run up to the given TimeSpan :)

Answer (score -1):

**See the code below: It may help you.**

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //return a message here;
    }
};
timer.start();
```

**And if you have an async task. Then do like below in `doInBackground` method:**

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
       //simply do your job
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //return a message here;
                return message;
            }
        };
        timer.start();
        return your_reult;
    }
```

Comment: a little description about what are you doing would be helpful